# Reading resources in vaadin from resource folder after building a JAR

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a Vaadin 24 project in which I load some static resources from */src/main/resources*. That works well in development mode but when packaged as JAR, the `InputStream` on all my resources is null.

I found out that Vaadin puts my resources in *BOOT-INF\classes* but they are not found in a production build JAR.

I am aware that there is a resource loading cheatsheet (https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/loading-resources) that I followed but that seems to work differently in production builds  - or I'm simply doing sth wrong.

My code is simple:

```
InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/myimg.png");
return is.readAllBytes();
```

myimg.png is in *src/main/resources* and after the build in *BOOT-INF\classes*.

Comment: What about with `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myimg.png");`?

Comment: I am in a static function, I tried InputStream is = Reader.class.getResourceAsStream(path); and that seems to work!

Comment: Yes, forget that. According to that cheatsheet, it looks like your resource tree should be below META-INF

Comment: Yes I tried that, too, but the documentation is not totally clear here in my eyes. I understood that the META-INF/resource path prefix is required when loading web resources in vaadin components.

Comment: You're right. They also say *The classpath resources are stored in the /src/main/resources folder and can be loaded using the Class.getResourceAsStream(name) or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(name) methods.* which therefore should work *although note the second one is NOT what you have*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue could be solved using the actuall Class, not the ClassLoader:

```
InputStream is = Reader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```